# Remove multiple items from list in Python

Tags: python, list

So, for example, I got a list: `myList=["asdf","ghjk","qwer","tyui"]`
I also have a list of index numbers of the items I want to remove: `removeIndexList=[1,3]` (I want to remove items 1 and 3 from the list above)

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: As a side note, don't call your list `list`; that hides the builtin type/constructor.

Comment: I'm asking because there's probably a better way to do it other than making a loop that looks like duct tape. And I used that name for the list, because it's an example and I didn't think it would be that big of a deal.

Comment: Even if you don't like the way you wrote it, show us the way you wrote it anyway. For one thing, that means if the details of your problem aren't entirely clear, we can just run your code to find out what you intended. For another, it gives us an idea of how experienced you are, so we can target answers appropriately. And finally, many people won't even look at a question that doesn't show any work, assuming you're just lazy; you got lucky and got a good answer this time, but if you scare off half the potential answerers you have to be twice as lucky…

Comment: This isn't a "Help me fix my code" question. This is a "What would be the best way to archieve x" question. I only tell you my code looks like "duct tape" because you asked for it. Other than that it's irrelevant. And no, I'm not lazy. I'm asking a genuine question for which I've been searching an answer for ~30 minutes. I've placed every bit of information needed in the question for it to be answerable. Why do you think a piece of code would help in this context? If anything, I think it'd only take up space.

Comment: I'm not saying you're lazy, I'm saying half the people here (and in plenty of other places) will unfairly _assume_ you are, and skip over your question, making you only half as likely to get a good answer. You may get lucky anyway, as you did, but why rely on that?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37484/discussion-between-mid-kid-and-abarnert)

Comment: Why? If you're going to refuse to give code when people ask for it, you're free to do so, and it's not going to hurt anyone but you.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use a list comprehension with `enumerate()`:

```
newlist = [v for i, v in enumerate(oldlist) if i not in removelist]
```

Making `removelist` a `set` instead will help speed things along:

```
removeset = set(removelist)
newlist = [v for i, v in enumerate(oldlist) if i not in removeset]
```

Demo:

```
>>> oldlist = ["asdf", "ghjk", "qwer", "tyui"]
>>> removeset = set([1, 3])
>>> [v for i, v in enumerate(oldlist) if i not in removeset]
['asdf', 'qwer']
```

Comment: When `len(removelist)` is 2, I doubt the set is helping. Especially when `len(list)` is only 4. In fact: `%timeit [v for i, v in enumerate(a) if i not in r]` gives me 1.15us; `%timeit [v for i, v in enumerate(a) if i not in set(r)]` 2.39, so it's 50% _slower_. (And only 290ns of that is the `set(r)` call; the rest is that hashing and looking up a hash takes longer than just walking a 2-element list.)

Comment: @abarnert: the `if` expression is executed for each element, so you are creating a new set each loop.

Comment: @abarnert: sure, extremely small inputs will fall over on constant cost, but *in general* using a `set` for membership testing is going to beat membership testing against a list, n'est pas?

Comment: After `s = set(r)`, `%timeit [v for i, v in enumerate(a) if i not in s]` gives me 1.49us, which is significantly slower than 1.15us.

Comment: Anyway, I think it's pretty common, for this kind of thing, to use a very short list of indices to remove, even if the list itself is long. So optimizing just in case you happen to get a long list of indices may be premature.

Comment: @abarnert: if the sequence of items to remove is of unknown length, I'd go with a set anyway; the alternative would be to gather stats on the expected number of items to remove.

Comment: @abarnert, there are stories aplenty where people haven't bothered to use simple optimisations like this. It doesn't hurt for the small cases and saves grief if the system needs to scale later. Especially when the original developer has moved on and it's in some deep but frequently used function.

Comment: @gnibbler: It's always a tradeoff. If you know you're using a short, static list, making your code slightly more complicated just to make it slightly slower is not a win. If you don't know what you're using, making it slightly more complicated and slightly slower in trivial cases but much faster in other cases _is_ a win. As always, you have to know what you're trying to code before you can pick the best way to write it.

Comment: @abanert On my system, the set version is consistently faster than the list version even with only two indices on both CPython 2.7 and 3.3 . (Tested with `python -m timeit -s "a=list(range(1000000))" -s "s=[1,3]" "[v for i, v in enumerate(a) if i not in s]"` (and `-s s={1,3}` in the other version).  It's the same when `a` is smaller (10 items).)

Answer (score 8):

The obvious way will not work:

```
list=["asdf","ghjk","qwer","tyui"]
removelist=[1,3] 
for index in removelist:
    del list[index]
```

The problem is that after you've deleted #1, "ghjk", everything after that gets shifted forward. So #3 is no longer "tyui", it's past the end of the list.

---

You can solve this by making sure you walk backward:

```
list=["asdf","ghjk","qwer","tyui"]
removelist=[1,3] 
for index in sorted(removelist, reverse=True):
    del list[index]
```

---

However, it's generally better to just build a new filtered list instead, as suggested by Martijn Pieters:

```
list = [v for i, v in enumerate(list) if i not in removelist]
```

Comment: Instead of `sorted(..., reverse=True)`, I have done the same thing with `reversed` with great success.

Comment: @SethMMorton: That only works if you know the `removelist` is guaranteed to be sorted in forward order. (And if you only know that because you're writing the list explicitly as a literal, you might as well write it in reversed order in the first place.)

Comment: I see what you mean.  I didn't look closely at your algorithm.  Yes, in this method you do need to sort anyway.

Comment: I know this is old, but can you explain how this works? `v for i` is a construct I've not run into yet, then all of it encompassed in a list seems interesting, but understandable, then I can understand `if i not in removelist` to help facilitate making the new list without those. But I'm not quite sure what's going on here.